# What is the impact of using the SHA1 certificates

Tags: certificate

I am using a certificate authority from windows 2003 machine and it issues certificates with SHA1 algorithm and these certificates are used in URLs. I came to know what all the browsers IE , Chrome , Mozilla , etc are going to stop supporting SHA1. Can you advise me what is the impact i am going to have in my URLs ??

Does these URLs will display only the security error message like "The URL which you are trying to access is not from trusted source" and if i add an exception i will still be able to view the web page or i will not be able to view the webpage completely even after adding the exception to the browser ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Google Statement](https://security.googleblog.com/2015/12/an-update-on-sha-1-certificates-in.html)

> Step 2: Blocking all SHA-1 certificates Starting January 1, 2017 at
>   the latest, Chrome will completely stop supporting SHA-1 certificates.
>   At this point, sites that have a SHA-1-based signature as part of the
>   certificate chain (not including the self-signature on the root
>   certificate) will trigger a fatal network error. This includes
>   certificate chains that end in a local trust anchor as well as those
>   that end at a public CA. In line with Microsoft Edge and Mozilla
>   Firefox, the target date for this step is January 1, 2017, but we are
>   considering moving it earlier to July 1, 2016 in light of ongoing
>   research. We therefore urge sites to replace any remaining SHA-1
>   certificates as soon as possible. Note that Chrome uses the
>   certificate trust settings of the host OS where possible, and that an
>   update such as Microsoft’s planned change will cause a fatal network
>   error in Chrome, regardless of Chrome’s intended target date.

According to Google's statement Chome will block alle network traffic to your site.